# EXCEL replace "False" with the word "NO"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets

I'm trying to print the word NO in the input if a condition is false. Here is what I'm currently trying

```
=IF (A2="a")AND(b2="b", "YES","NO")
```

It seems like this would work but I keep getting this error | `Formula parse error.`

I'm new to EXCEL and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be great Thanks!

Comment: Try `=IF (AND(A2="a", b2="b"), "YES","NO")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `If()`  and `AND` like this:

`=IF(AND(A2="a",b2="b"),"Yes","No")`.

Pay special attention to the closing `)` in `And()`, I've frustrated myself many times by forgetting that and wondering why my `If` formula wasn't working.

Answer (score 6):

You were close. Try this

```
=IF(AND(A2="a",B2="b"),"YES","NO")
```

Answer (score 2):

Format the cell with a custom format

```
[=1]"YES";"NO"
```

Then convert the formula result in the cell to an integer.

```
=INT(AND(A2="a",B2="b"))
```

Comment: Now that is different and neat.

Comment: =(A2="a")*(B2="b") should also work with this custom format